# Include text on the splash screen Android

Tags: java, android, xml, splash-screen

I am using this popular method from this site to make a splash screen: 
[Splash Screens the Right Way](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way).

And I want to display a translated text "loading" to different languages. This was asked earlier in the comments section, and the author replied, but I do not know how to do what he says. Here is what he replied: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/#comment-2633426495

How can i draw the text on the screen? (If it's posible) Or as it says there, How to "include" it in the drawable?

Is another method preferable?

Comment: its simple..just create a layout with Linear or Relative.. put ImageView and TextView inside it..

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and follow the guideline 

there to provide quality answer.

Comment: @Chipkat did you found the solution....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Here is my splash activity xml
This is an easy solution and places the text bellow the image.

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/colorIcons"
tools:context=".SplashActivity">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splashImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/splashText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary_text"
        android:textSize="36sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I had not realized that what I was trying to do was a "loading screen", this comes AFTER the "splash screen" that I am referring to in the question above, which cannot be modified, because it is a theme given in manifest.xml, and it loads before application is ready.
But the "load screen" can be customized, because the application is already able to display the content of the activity.

Comment: @Chipkat That's weird, because, in my case, I have no need to create a "load screen", only a splash screen. But I can't add text to my splash screen. I added a png with a text, but it won't be responsible in every screen and It won't change the text according to the user language. Did u found out anything about it?